# Mocha - coffeescript syntax

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, mocha.js

I'm converting some Mocha tests from JS to coffeescript and having issues with the `beforeEach` function. Below is what I currently have, but the `data` variable isn't being recognized in the test cases. Any suggestions?

```
beforeEach ->
  data =
    name: "test name"
    to: "alice"
    from: "bob"
    object1: "foo"
    object2: "bar"
```

And here is the original:

```
beforeEach(function(){
  data = {
    name: "test name",
    to: "Alice",
    from: "Bob",
    object1: "foo",
    object2: "bar"
  }
});
```

Comment: The coffeescript you provided is exactly the same as the js. Where do you use `data`? coffeescript moves all variables to the smallest scope, if you need `data` outside of the `beforeEach`, you have to declare it outside.

Comment: @muistooshort I say that in my 2nd sentence ;)

Comment: @darthmaim: I was talking about the "The coffeescript you provided is exactly the same as the js." part, perhaps I'm being overly picky :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your JavaScript version:

```
beforeEach(function(){
    data = { ... }
});
```

`data` is a global variable because it isn't explicitly scoped to the function using `var data`. In your CoffeeScript version:

```
beforeEach ->
  data = ...
```

`data` is a local variable inside the `beforeEach` callback function because that's [how variables work in CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org/#lexical-scope):

> **Lexical Scoping and Variable Safety**
>
> The CoffeeScript compiler takes care to make sure that all of your
>   variables are properly declared within lexical scope — you never need
>   to write `var` yourself.

and your CoffeeScript ends up like this JavaScript:

```
beforeEach(function(){
    var data = { ... }
});
```

and `data` is hidden away where you can't see it.

One solution is to manually create `data` outside the `beforeEach`:

```
describe 'Whatever', ->
  data = null
  beforeEach ->
    data = ...
```

That will give you the same `data` inside and outside `beforeEach` and `data` should be what you're expecting inside each of your `it`s.

Another option is to use an instance variable for `data`:

```
beforeEach ->
  @data = ...
```

and then look at `@data` inside your `it`s.

I'd prefer the first version (manually scoping `data` with `data = null`) because you never know when you're going to accidentally overwrite someone else's instance variable.